# Swing in dropdown using css3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, transition

I'm having a headache seeking for solution to achieve this swing-in dropdown effect in a website of mine. Professionals, could you please explain how do I get this effect? This is the website that has the same what I want http://reyochoa.com/jake/
I inspected their css using developer tools but I didn't notice anything in the css that can do the job for me. I'm guessing they used some jQuery plugin for that, I'm not sure. Could you guys please take a minute and explain how I can achieve this effect? Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop-down is using javascript/jQuery. It can be achieved with just `css` so that is something to keep in mind.

[image: before hover state]

Look at this line, `<div style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; left: 162px;">`. Do you see those inline styles? That is from the scripting language animating styles.

Watch as they change when hovered,

[image: after hover state]

This is how it looks once it is finished animating, `<div style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; left: 162px;">`